# Add field when adding new content in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-fields, drupal-field-api

I'd like to ask a tricky question to you about Drupal.

I created a new content type which includes lots of fields.

I want to find a module that adds a 'Add another' link to the adding content screen which will duplicate certain fields.

Example:

I have fields named Panel1 Photo, Panel1 Info, Panel2 Photo, Panel2 Info...

When adding a new content of this type, if I want to enter 3 panels, I want this module to create 3 fields of Photo and Info for me, and maybe 4 or 5 at other times.

I hope you will understand what I ask.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have each field set to allow multiple values which would put the add another button you talk about. If you make a field collection with the [field collection module](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) you will be able to group those fields together and you can allow multiple values for the field collection. Let me know if you haven't found the add another button.

Comment: I will try that and give you a feedback, but I want to be sure that you understood me right.

If I want to create a new content, which I have created its content type with that module, will I be able to enter 10 sets of fields and when creating another content with same type, 20 sets of fields?

Comment: You cannot actually add fields to a content type once it is created. Drupal is not designed in a way that that will ever be an option. However drupal does allow you to add multiple values to the same field. So your photo field can have a value 1, value 2 and value 3. This is done by going to the manage fields page on the content type, clicking edit on the right of the field and changing the value of the "Number of values" box. -edit- field collections will help group your fields so when you hit add another it will add another of all of them.

Comment: Thank you man, that was exatly what I was looking for.

An extra question raises though, can I set multiple collections?

Answer (score 0):

Install the [field collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module then in the content type create a field collection with panel and photo fields.

When you create your first content page you will start with one panel and photo and a + button. The + button gives you the ability to create ever more panels and photos grouped together.